# Why does unbuffer command affect time command?

Tags: bash, shell, time

I noticed something odd when using the unbuffer command with
time command. Here I just want to see how long takes to find
a certain file in my system:

```
time find . -name unixstuff
```

output is :

```
./Documents/CProgramming/2031/unix/Awk/unixstuff
0.011u 0.173s 0:00.38 47.3%     0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

but when I write unbuffer before this command output is :

```
./Documents/CProgramming/2031/unix/Awk/unixstuff
0.01user 0.17system 0:00.38elapsed 47%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4656maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+338minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Note that 0.17s is expanded to 0.17system and other expansions of shorthand happened. I would like to know why this change of 
behaviour happens. I don't want an unpredictable output 
in my pipes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `time` in the first command is a shell keyword. The `time` in the second command is the executable. See the `type` output of `time`:

```
$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
```

The command `unbuffer` needs a program as argument not a shell keyword. It cannot interpret a shell keyword, this is a `bash` internal keyword.

And the difference in the output you see is the difference of those two implementations of the `time` command. Just use the abolute path in the first command that you have the same behavior as in the second one:

```
/usr/bin/time find . -name unixstuff
```

Comment: Alternatively, `unbuffer bash -c 'time find . -name unixstuff'`